# Fixed div inside div with other div scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm very sorry for the unclear title but I do not know how to describe it in a title.

I have a 2 divs inside a content layer. 1 div I want to stay fixed, the other div I want to be able to scroll and I am not able to do it myself.

Here is a small fiddle;

```css
.contentlayer {
    text-align: center;
}
.innerlayer {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    min-width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 80%;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
}
.content {

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Css Static Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="innerlayer">
            <div class="contentlayer">
                <div class="header">
                    I want this div to stay in place. but also stay in the same position as if it weren't fixed, this will be a header.
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    test
                    <script>
                        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            document.write("<br>");
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of how the real thing would look like:
[image]
[image]

I want the header in the first picture to stay in place, whilst everything else I want to be able to scroll down.

It needs to be a bit like this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768098/fixed-non-scrolling-footer-inside-a-div) but that the scrollbar does not extend into the footer, or in this case, the header.

Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```css
.contentlayer {
    text-align: center;
}
.innerlayer {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    min-width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 80%;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    height:15%;
    width:100%;
    background:#f00;
}
.content {
  bottom:0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:80%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Css Static Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="innerlayer">
            <div class="contentlayer">
                <div class="header">
                    I want this div to stay in place. but also stay in the same position as if it weren't fixed, this will be a header.
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    test
                    <script>
                        for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            document.write("<br>line"+i);
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah it worked sort of when I added width: 100%; to .content but the top:17%; doesnt really work, I need it to automatically go under the .header. Any way I can do that?

Comment: Thanks! Im just testing it on my real website and then iil flag your answer as answered if it does work :D

Comment: It sadly does not seem to work on my normal website since it puts the headers to the left and everything is inside each other and the text extends underneath the content div. Here is a link for a fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xa7astgg/) I really dont know how to fix this overflowing etc without using height: 10%; but using something like height: auto;

Comment: 1) add to .header > width:100%;
2) height: auto; will overflow in some cases if you don't set it to value of 100% - .content:height;

check modified answer

Comment: That worked for the header, if you check again, the body is still inside the header. Im sorry that I cant figure this out myself but I hate css because of this lol. Do you know how I can fix this, and that its automatically under the header?

Comment: you can by fix the header and content height both to 100% like 20% for header and 80% for content or what ever you see better for the values